# Can't compile/use ObjectListView in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, objectlistview

I want to use ObjectListView in a project coded in VS 2010.

Therefore I did the following things:

- Downloaded the project
- Opened both ObjectListView.sln to convert it to a VS2010 project
- Added one of them to my project-folder in VS 2010
- Added the project-assembly to my project
- Added the namespace xmlns:o="clr-namespace:BrightIdeasSoftware;assembly=ObjectListView"

It compiles but it doesn't find any of its classes in my project. That means after entering the namespace: "

Does anyone know what I can do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObjectListView project in the solution is missing "Filters.cs". It's located in the directory, just not added to the project.

Add it to the project, and everything will build (using VS2010, and ObjectListView.sln).

**EDIT:**

It looks like you're creating a WPF project. ObjectListView is intended to be used in WinForms applications.

Comment: OK it builds, but now I've got the same problem as with ObjectListView2008.sln, even though the namespace is correct I can't use anything like <olv:ObjectListView>

Comment: Are you creating a WPF project (judging from your comment)? As far as I can see, ObjectListView is meant to be used in WinForms applications, not WPF applications.

Comment: Yeah I created a WPF project.
Is it somehow possible to use it in a WPF application anyways?

Comment: Apparently it is, googling "using winform in wpf" yields several results, including one from the msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx). I've never done it though, and don't know what (if any) the limitations are, or how it will integrate with other WPF controls and the rest of the WPF framework. My gut feeling however says that you'll be engaging in an uphill battle, to achieve something that can be achieved by WPF itself without an unreasonable amount of effort.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I'm better off with Winforms then.
You know any good tutorials on how to customize controls in WPF so they are like OLV?

Comment: For ListView specific, http://blog.vascooliveira.com/wpf-listview-styling-tutorial-part-i/ is the best I could find in a quick search. For some reason I can't seem to find websites with nice compelling demos and screenshots for WPF, but some more elaborate googling should give something useful. Don't hesitate to include Silverlight in your searches too; for practical purposes, the ideas and concepts are almost identical, although sometimes the actual implementation details may differ somewhat. Good luck on your efforts!